# DJANGO 3.0: List out of QuerySet (Basic-Level question)

Tags: python, django, list, django-views

It is very beginner level question, I know. But can anyone just tell me how to make List out of QuerySet.

I am getting queryset with following query:

```
sports = Category.objects.all()
print(sports)
```

Output:

> <QuerySet [<Category: Golf>, <Category: Cricket>, <Category: Football>, <Category: Golf>, <Category: Hockey>]>

But what I **require**, is:

```
print(sports)
```

Desired Output:

> ['Baseball', 'Cricket', 'Football', 'Golf',  'Hockey']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with list comprehension

```
[category for category in Category.objects.all() ]
```

Comment: Got my results.

Answer (score 0):

It brought my answer:

```
[category.type for category in Category.objects.all()]
```